# using jquery with a user script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get div id. in div, if a tag contains textToSearch, I want to hide it. How to do this?

Also I want to run this script before page load. I don't want to see page's pass.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
     <div class="whitebox">
            <div class="content">
                <div id="t512848" class="entry0">
                     <a>test</a>
                </div>
                <div id="t512849" class="entry0">
                     <a>galatasaray!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

User Script 
...

```
function main($) {
    textToSearch = "test";
    $(".content").children().each(function(n, i) {
    var id = this.id;
    $('div.entry0').each(function(index){
        var that = this;
        $(this).find("a:contains('"+textToSearch+"')").each(function(index) {               
            //$(#id).hide();
            console.log(this);
        });
    }); 
   });
}

addJQuery(main);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `each` method, you can use `has` method and hide the divs:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

```
$('.entry0').has("a:contains('"+textToSearch+"')").hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function main($) {
    textToSearch = "test";

    $(".content").children().each(function(n, i) {
        var id = this.id;
        $('div.entry0').each(function(index){
            var that = this;
            $(this).find("a:contains('"+textToSearch+"')").each(function(index, element) {               
                $(element).hide();
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This example will get the id of the parent div for all anchor tags with matching text. I also included a link to a jsfiddle example.

**HTML**

```
<div id="d1" class="entry0">
    <a>test</a>
</div>
<div id="d2" class="entry0">
    <a>test1</a>
</div>
<div id="d3" class="entry0">
    <a>test</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
textToSearch = "test";

$(".entry0").each(function(index) {
    $(this).find("a").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).text() == textToSearch) {
            alert($(this).parent().prop("id"));
        }
    });
});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/X3pmR/)

**EDIT**

Oh, I did not know about has. Check out the other answer and use has and you have a winner. :)